# How to show that a complex function is even?

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Let $f(z)$ be analytic in the unit disk $|z| \lt 1$. Prove that if $f'(0)=f^{(3)}(0)=f^{(5)}(0)=...=0$, then $f(-z)=f(z)$ for all z in this disk. That is, show that $f$ is an even function.

We are only given two pieces of information,
1. $f$ is analytic in the unit disk
2. all of its odd numbered derivatives equal zero when evaluating at zero.
I know that number 2 is true for even functions (for example $cos z$), but is it only true for even functions because I don't know how I can use the fact that $f$ is analytic to show that it is even.

Comment: As you tagged use taylor expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is analytic on the domain so : $\forall |z|<1,f(z)=f(0)+f'(0)z+\frac{f^{(2)}(0)}{2!}z^2+\frac{f^{(3)}(0)}{3!}z^3+\frac{f^{(4)}(0)}{4!}z^4+\frac{f^{(5)}(0)}{5!}z^5+\frac{f^{(6)}(0)}{6!}z^6+\dots$
So on the domain : $$f(z)=f(0)+\frac{f^{(2)}(0)}{2!}z^2+\frac{f^{(4)}(0)}{4!}z^4+\frac{f^{(6)}(0)}{6!}z^6+\dots\\=f(0)+\frac{f^{(2)}(0)}{2!}(-z)^2+\frac{f^{(4)}(0)}{4!}(-z)^4+\frac{f^{(6)}(0)}{6!}(-z^6)+\dots=f(-z)$$

So $f$ is even.

Comment: So this means that if a function is analytic and has every odd numbered derivative equal to zero when evaluated at zero then it must be even. Then the same would be true if a function is analytic and has every even numbered derivative equal to zero when evaluated at zero then it must be odd.

Comment: Yes it would be also true